# Can I add admin links with dynamic JavaScript from my controller in CodeIgniter 2?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, dynamic, admin, hyperlink

I want to cache most of my controllers’ output, but some of the pages need to have links so I can add and edit the info. If I set up a “js” controller and routed “global.js” to a “global” method of a “js” controller, couldn’t I use PHP to dynamically add some JavaScript to “global.js” only if I’m logged in as an admin? Is there a better way to only cache pages if the visitor is not an admin?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what caching and a global.js file have to do with each other. Perhaps some more detail or rephrasing would be valuable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to show add/edit/delete links on a page, but only if I'm logged in as an admin. I also want to cache the page. CodeIgniter's caching doesn't support conditional caching, so I needed a workaround to insert the links dynamically. I'm using PHP to dynamically write JavaScript so I can use jQuery to insert the links.

1) I set this in /config/routes.php:

```
$route['js/global.js'] = 'js/global_scripts'; // function can't be called "global" since it's a PHP keyword
```

2) Then I have this function in my js controller:

```
public function global_scripts() {
    $this->output->set_header("content-type: application/x-javascript")
    $this->load->view('js/global'); // see below
} // global_scripts
```

3) And this is the js/global view:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    <?php if($this->is_admin == TRUE): ?> // from my auth + MY_Controller
    alert("you're an admin"); // or whatever JS I want
    <?php endif; ?>
});
```

In my view files I have a regular JavaScript link:

```
<script src="/js/global.js"></script>
```

If I visit the page and I'm logged in as an admin, I get an alert, and I don't get an alert if I'm not logged in as an admin. So now I can have the script insert add/edit/delete links only if I'm logged in.